# Importing module that uses getElementById in VueJS component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, blockly

I am trying to import Blockly (via node-blockly from npm) into a VueJS component, but the javascript part of Blockly contains getElementById() calls, which causes an error as ***document.getElementById()*** is not available in VueJS.

Any idea how to get around this?

(Edit) Code Example:

```
<template> 
 <div class="hello"> 
   <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;">
   </div> 
    <xml id="toolbox" ref=toolbox style="display: none"> 
     <block type="controls_if"></block> 
     <block type="text"></block> <block type="text_print"></block> 
    </xml> 
   </div> 
</template> 
<script> 
 import Blockly from "node-blockly" 
 export default { name: 'hello' } 
 var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')}); 
</script>
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  document.getElementById works fine with vue.js.  Can you provide a code example of what isn't working?

Comment: I think you are using the webpack version which has eslint? If yes then you need to allow browser in eslintrc. If this is your case then I shall post an answer.

Comment: I opted for no eslint when I created the webpack project (using vue cli).

Answer (score 3):

I supose is v2.

Try in [mounted event](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted)

```html
<template> 
 <div class="hello"> 
   <div id="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;">
   </div> 
    <xml id="toolbox" ref=toolbox style="display: none"> 
     <block type="controls_if"></block> 
     <block type="text"></block> <block type="text_print"></block> 
    </xml> 
   </div> 
</template> 
<script> 
 import Blockly from "node-blockly" 
 export default { 
   name: 'hello',
   data(){
     return {
       workspace: null
     }
   },
   mounted(){
     this.workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')});
   }
 } 
</script>
```

Comment: I am afraid that didn't make a difference. The getElementById() function when calling the inject isn't actually the problem. It is a getElementById() within the Blockly JS.
I guess the additional elements (xml, toolbox etc.) need to be registered properly as child components. I will try this and post the results here....

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are using VueJS version 2, you can access the reference to an element using `this.$refs.myElement` after tagging your element in the template.

Example:

```
<div ref="blocklyDiv" style="height: 480px; width: 600px;">

mounted () {
  this.workspace = Blockly.inject(this.$refs.blocklyDiv);
}
```

Then, just do the same for your toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        console.log('blockly');
           var workspace = Blockly.inject('blocklyDiv', {
             toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')
           });

           var blocklyArea = document.getElementById('blocklyArea');
           var blocklyDiv = document.getElementById('blocklyDiv');

           var workspace = Blockly.inject(blocklyDiv, {
              toolbox: document.getElementById('toolbox')
           });

  ....
},
```

Comment: Update- this approach does not allow for the implementation of Blockly.JavaScript.workspaceToCode(workspace); Investigating.